# Abstract Sealed Classes

Tags: .net, c++-cli, abstract-class, sealed

Just a small question about c++/cli.
Abstract classes have abstract methods to be implemented by derived classes,
sealed classes dont allow inheritance.

So why we have some classes in .NET base class library defined as abstract sealed, and you can find plenty .. ??!

Comment: Examples?  This is an interesting design decision to me, so I wanted to see which ones did it :)

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.aspx

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It is equivalent to "static class" in the C# language.  The language that was used to write almost all of the BCL classes.  All the methods must be static.  Declaring it abstract and sealed prevents anybody from deriving from the class and creating an instance of it.

The class methods are the exact equivalent of free functions in the C and C++ language.  Something the CLR does not support.

Comment: i totally agree with you, becuause it looks like JAVA'S MATH class for instance, but why the msdn documentation state that this isn't possible or right if u can do it ??!

Comment: @Ebraheem Najjar: It's only possible to do this directly at the IL level. The compiler won't let you write a `sealed abstract` class directly.

Comment: The IL attributes on a class are distinct from the keywords in the language.  In C#, it makes no sense to declare a class sealed *and* abstract, it will complain.  Declaring it static is what turns these IL attributes on.  There is no CLR analogue for a 'static' class.