# Abstract class cannot be sealed in c#?

Tags: c#, oop, .net-4.0, static, abstract-class

I read somewhere

**"Abstract and Sealed modifiers are equivalent to a class which is static"**

I also found that

**"When you declare a static class, internally the compiler marks the class abstract and sealed, and creates a private constructor in the IL code"**

so, I decided to do this:

```
static class A
{
    public static void test()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("test");
    }
}
```

**Now, the class "A" cannot be inherited nor instantiated.**

**So, let us write a `class B` using `abstract` to prevent instantiation and using `sealed` to prevent inheritance.**

But, this approach fails.

which should be equivalent to

```
public abstract sealed class B
{
    private B()
    {

    }
    public void test()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("test");
    }
}
```

`But I recieve an error stating "error CS0418:`B': an abstract class cannot be sealed or static"` . Any ideas why this is not possible ?

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: why do you want abstract sealed class? It makes no sense.

Comment: I dont want it. I was just checking if these modifiers are equivalent to a static class as was said.

Comment: A sealed class cannot be extended or inherited from, yet an abstract class *must* be extended to be of use.

Comment: What the compilers does is not necessarily allowed to be followed by developers

Comment: @nowhewhomustnotbenamed. "A sealed class cannot be used as a base class. For this reason, it cannot also be an abstract class." from MSDN

Comment: Do you have links for the claim that static classes are compiled to abstract sealed ones? Never heard that before & I'm interested in reading more.

Comment: The compiler doesn't allow you to do `abstract sealed class`, even though that's the equivalent of what `static class` does. It expects you to use `static class` to do that.

Comment: @TimS. Makes sense, Thanks. But, the thing that is bothering me is `Can you make equivalent of static class with out using the word 'static' `?

Comment: @Alireza: good point. Agreed. But, I am just brain storming and researching.

Comment: I don't see a point in being able to create a class that works like a static class *without the use of the keyword `static`*. Can you point out any benefits of being able to do so? Remember that it takes work to add features to a language, and in this case I fail completely to see a point to allowing this. Abstract classes are meant for inheritance, sealed classes prevent inheritance, it makes no sense to try to combine the two to "mimic" something already possible in another way.

Comment: Surely you only need to give it a private default constructor and no other constructor? (This ignores using reflection to cheat!)

Comment: Most likely you read it [here: Abstract Sealed Classes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3644004/abstract-sealed-classes) which talks about managed C++ classes, ie. C++ syntax. It thus looks like a "trick" to get the C++ compiler to emit what amounts to a .NET static class. C# has never allowed this as basically it makes no sense, but perhaps it was an acceptable solution in C++. C# is a new language, however, and they did not make C# by removing stuff from C/C++, they started fresh and added what was needed. This was not.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen: Good point. So, I assume there is none which serves the purpose of static except itself. Finally, I think: 1. There is no point in doing so. 2. As you say, it does not make sense

Comment: @nowhewhomustnotbenamed. no, you can't make a class both `abstract` and `sealed` without using the `static` keyword in C#. You could make something that works similarly by making it `sealed` with a `private` constructor, but it won't be marked `abstract` in the compiled IL, or have handy features like the compiler making sure you only put `static` members in it.

Comment: When you translate `abstract sealed class` to VB.NET you get `MustInherit CannotInherit Class`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Having checked the IL of the System.Directory class (which is static), it is declared in IL as:

```
.class public auto ansi abstract sealed beforefieldinit System.IO.Directory
extends System.Object
{
    ...
```

Further, this article (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229038.aspx) suggests that the CLR handles static classes as abstract sealed classes to support languages that do not support directly delcaring static classes (eg C++).

Thus in conclusion, static classes in C# are syntactic sugar for sealed abstract classes with private constructors. I for one am glad of that as "static" is a lot easier to write and a lot easier to get right.

Answer (score 3):

By definition a `sealed` class enables you to prevent the inheritance of a class or certain class members that were previously marked virtual.

`Abstract` keyword enables you to create classes and class members that are incomplete and must be implemented in a derived class.
(Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173150.aspx)

This would imply that any class marked abstract would not be able to be sealed, since you wouldn't be able to derive it anywhere.

The code you mentioned doesn't make any sense.

Comment: is it not a valid answer?

Comment: people are downvoting this because you didn't include relevant sources (MSDN or the like). I didn't downvote it myself, for the record.

Comment: If static classes are undeed compiled down to sealed abstract classes, then your claim that sealed abstract classes makes no sense is cleary nonsensical...

Comment: They are not. .NET supports static classes, so they are not "compiled down" to sealed abstract classes. There is no such beast (sealed abstract class) in .NET.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen, you are mistaken sir. I have checked the IL of the Directory class in Telerik's JustCompile and it is defined in IL as "class public auto ansi abstract sealed beforefieldinit System.IO.Directory extends System.Object". No mention of static there.

Comment: Then the IL is lacking the concept as well. The class is still static, it will not be an instance class. A non-static class allows non-static fields and other members, a static class does not, and these classes does not in any way allow that. But I agree, I'm mistaken about the terminology to use here.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen: There is no such concept as "static class" in the CLR. The C# compiler compiles a static class as an abstract sealed class.

Answer (score 1):

All answers somehow take the technical point of view. Such as: the class can't be "must inherit" and "can't inherit" at the same time. But I think that is not the main reason, as clearly, the "static" is just that.
I think David Amo's answer has touched the real answer a bit, by stating: "it is a lot easier to get right".

I am convinced that Anders Hejlsberg's idea when designing C# was to eliminate ambiguity and thus decrease a chance for error. That's why "virtual" goes with "override" (override has to be explicit, not implicit as in Java). And in this case, "abstract"+"sealed" would be the same as "static". Two ways of defining the same principle. This is:
  - more error prone (imagine you have abstract somewhere and put sealed there accidently without noticing, onw compiler prevents that)
  - more difficult to work with (imagine you want to search for all static classes in your project)

So my point is, this entire design leads the developers the right way of doing things.